# Proving estimated accuracy of exclusively combining two classification models

Tags: mathematical-statistics

I have two classification models; $\text{model}_1$ and $\text{model}_2$. $\text{model}_1$ averages $80\%$ accuracy (on a hold-out dev set) and $\text{model}_2$ averages $50\%$ accuracy (on a hold-out dev set). Given an unseen sample, I will random use either $\text{model}_1$ with $\alpha$ probability **or** $\text{model}_2$ with $(1-\alpha)$ probability.

It seems natural that my expected accuracy of exclusively choosing either $\text{model}_1$ or $\text{model}_2$ would be
$\alpha\times80\% + (1-\alpha)\times50\%$

But how do I prove such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be the random variable to present average accuracy on the unseen sample. Then $Y$ has following properties:

$$\begin{cases}
\Pr(Y=50\%) = \alpha  & \text{ for model 1}\\
\Pr(Y=80\%) = 1-\alpha &\text{ for model 2}
\end{cases}
$$
According to the definition of the expectation of the random variable, we have 
the expected accuracy be:

$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{E}(Y) &= \sum y\Pr(Y=y)\\
&= 50\% \alpha + 80\%(1-\alpha) 
\end{align*}$$